# Bootstrap: 100% height footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue with the height of my footer.

On the mobile website the footer is as I expect but when I take a look on desktop the background color gone.

[image: On mobile]

And this is what I see on my desktop:
[image: And this is what I see on my desktop:]

Here is my code:

```css
    footer {
      background-color: #232323;
      height: 100%;
      border-top: #ebe050 5px solid;
    }
    footer .widget-title {
      color: #ebe050;
    }
    footer .widget-content {
      color: #eaeaea;
    }
```

```html
        <div class="row">
        <footer>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="widget-title">
                    <h3>About us</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="widget-content">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean elementum lacus in lacus dictum, vitae pulvinar sem tempor. Nulla rutrum, lectus eget pulvinar egestas, quam lacus luctus ante, eget facilisis magna leo ut ipsum. Aenean tempus lorem arcu, id dapibus elit aliquet et.</p>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="widget-title">
                    <h3>About us</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="widget-content">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean elementum lacus in lacus dictum, vitae pulvinar sem tempor. Nulla rutrum, lectus eget pulvinar egestas, quam lacus luctus ante, eget facilisis magna leo ut ipsum. Aenean tempus lorem arcu, id dapibus elit aliquet et.</p>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="widget-title">
                    <h3>Categories</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="widget-content">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Girl vs Girl</li>
                        <li>MMA</li>
                        <li>WWE</li>
                        <li>Street</li>
                        <li>Sparring</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: maybe it is stupid question but - does your desktop browser support HTML5?

Comment: Yes it supports HTML5, i'm using the latest version of Google Chrome. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things.

You could remove `footer` from `footer .widget-*whatever*` scene as the browser will just select anything with the class `.widget-*whatever*` - but it's totally up to you.

Second thing, what you could do is change `height` to `min-height` but please make sure that the container the footer is in has a **SET HEIGHT** otherwise having a percentage for your height will be pointless (because how can the browser take a percentage of nothing?). Having `min-height`, this will force the element to be at least 100% - meaning if you don't fill the full space, you'll have blank space at the bottom but if you use `max-height`, it will be the set height given or less, meaning everything looks normal, if it fits in the given space.

Hopefully, this answer sorts your problem.

**CSS** for you.

```
footer {
    background-color: #232323;
    min-height: 100%; /*Make sure the container for the footer has a set height*/
    border-top: #ebe050 5px solid;
}
.widget-title {
    color: #ebe050;
}
.widget-content {
    color: #eaeaea;
}
```

You may want to try `max-height` and `min-height` and see what one works best for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help and the explaining! It's solved right now, I've added a container outside the footer.

Comment: No bother, I'm glad my answer helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the div class="row" inside the footer Tag, so the footer should contain the rows and cols.

UPDATE: Working example:
http://www.bootply.com/render/ZnruhjLe8C

Comment: Sorry, it didn't show the tags in the comment; edited.